# Function with "int x[][n]" as argument

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

When defining a function this way:

```
void someFunction(int x[][n]){
   //Function instruction
}
```

What is the x objet exactly:

Is it an array of n pointers to an array of undefined amount of integers?

What is the synonymous definition using pointers syntax.

How the program allocat the x object in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define function as

```
void someFunction(int x[][n]) { ... }
```

copiler interprets it as

```
void someFunction(int (*x)[n]) { ... }
```

> Is it an array of n pointers to an array of undefined amount of integers?

No. `x` is a pointer to an array of `n` integers.

> What is the synonymous definition using pointers syntax.

```
void someFunction(int (*x)[n]) { ... }
```

Comment: what's the difference if you defined it this way:
`void someFunction(int x[]){...}`
or `void someFunction(int x[n]){...}`

Comment: @rullof: If you are asking what the difference between `void someFunction(int x[])` and `void someFunction(int x[n])` is, there is no difference. If you are asking the difference between those and `void someFunction(int x[][n])`, then, the former, `x` is a pointer to `int`, but, in the latter, `x` is a pointer to an array of n `int`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil; I think the only difference is, the second one `someFunction(int x[n])` will give compile time error if `n` is not globally defined.

Answer (score 0):

It is a pointer to a block of memory of unspecified size, which is divisible my `n`.

Indexing into it takes the form `x[i][j] == *((int*)x + i*n + j)`

The synonym. which isn't very well known, is the following:

```
void someFunction(int (*x)[n]){
   //Function instruction
}
```

It's not the same as an array of pointers to blocks of memory, which takes the form `int** x`.

Comment: Do you mean by a block, a multidimensional array?

Comment: @rullof, yes. Although, I said block to be precise, and avoid confusion with an array of pointers to arrays `T**`.

Comment: The x object always points to the first element, the brackets are just semantic. It could be multidimentional or not as a `int a` is the same as `int a[1]` and `int b[n]` is the same as `int b[1][n]`. Am i right?

Comment: @rullof, `x` points to the first *array*, which is of type `int[n]`, and not to the first element. It could be made to decay further into a pointer to the first element, however. You won't be able to pass the address of `int a`, but you would be able to pass the address of `int a[n]` or just pass `int a[m][n]` for various `m`.

Comment: @rullof, as a rule of thumb, when passed to a function, the outermost "dimension" of a multidimensional array decays into a pointer to the following dimensions.

Comment: What if we use the & operator the pass the adress, and another indicator to not exceed the size of a that is one element.

Comment: @rullof, take a look at the following http://ideone.com/Npsgg3
It details what I was trying to say much more succinctly

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42143/discussion-between-rullof-and-storyteller)

Comment: This is wrong. `x[i][j]` is *not* `*(x + i*n + j)`. It's not even the right type.

Comment: @StoryTeller: "x points to the first array, which is of type int[n], and not to the first element." The first array *is* the first element -- the first element of the two-dimensional array.

Comment: @newacct, It was only a missed cast. The arithmetic is correct now. As for you second comment, I prefer to avoid explicitly saying it's an array of arrays when explaining it to someone who seems a begginner. It causes too much confusion with the common use of a `T**`.